# Inserting items into array with bracket syntax doesnt affect length?

Tags: javascript

An array's length does not increase when adding items with bracket syntax. How do you update the length?

Example:

```js
const a = [];
a['u123'] = 1;
a['u456'] = 2;
a.length; // returns 0
```

Comment: because with your syntax, your are creating object properties, not new array values

Comment: you must use the method from array to insert itens like: `a.push(1)` or `a = [1,2]`

Answer (score 4):

Arrays do not have keys, so your way of accessing them is also wrong. You could instead use `push` to add values to the array and the values will be index based, not key based.

```js
const a = [];
a.push('u123');
a.push('u456');
console.log(a.length);
```

Or you could make your data an object instead, to have a key-value pair:

```js
const a = {};
a['u123'] = 1;
a['u456'] = 2;
console.log(Object.keys(a).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not adding items to the array instead you are inserting entries (key-value pairs) to your object.

You can check the length of the entries using the below syntax:

```
Object.keys(a).length // returns 2
```

If you want to add items to the array, use the below syntax:

```
a.push(1);
a.push('u123')

// ES6 syntax using spread operator
a = [...a, 2, 'u456']
a.length // returns 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the length of an associative array you need to use the Object.keys length

Like so:

```
console.log(Object.keys(a).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the length you need to use `push`. If you are using brackets you are adding a new property to an object (remember that an array is an object).

The length property return the number of elements in the array (not the properties).

```
var arrA = new Array();
var arrB = new Array();

arrA['propertyOne'] = 1; //add property 'propertyOne' with value 1 to the object arrA
arrA.push(2);


arrB.push(1);
arrB.push(2);

console.log(arrA); // [2, propertyOne: 1]
console.log(arrA[0]); // 2
console.log(arrA['propertyOne']); // 1
console.log(arrA.hasOwnProperty('propertyOne')); // true
console.log(arrA.length); // 1

console.log(arrB); // [1, 2]
console.log(arrB.length); // 2
```